# Django CK editor images not displaying, a quick F12 shows that images are comming from backend but not displaying, please help me to fix this

Tags: python, reactjs, django, react-hooks

I am trying to develop a blog application using react and django and for description section i choose django ckeditor.

when i upload a image using ck editor it's showing in adminpanel section no warnings because i double checked every path of django ckeditor . but those images are not displaying in the front end it's just showing a blank image field. but it's working on a simple html file not working with React . images are totally blank where i am missing ? if i do a quick F12 to check if the image is coming from backend or not . it is coming there but just not showing, Text is showing just not image

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios  from 'axios';
const BlogDetail =(props)=>{
    const [blog,setBlog]=useState({});
    useEffect(()=>{
        const slug=props.match.params.id;
    
    const fetchFata=async()=>{
        try{
            const res=await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/blog/${slug}`);
            setBlog(res.data);
        }
        catch (err){

        }
    };
    fetchFata();
    },[props.match.params.id]);




    const createBlog = () => {
        return {__html: blog.content}
    };

    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (word) => {
        if (word)
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        return '';
    };
    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <h1 className="display-2">{blog.title}</h1>
            <h2 className='text-muted mt-3'>Category: {capitalizeFirstLetter(blog.category)}</h2>
            <h4>Last commit {blog.updated}</h4>
            <div className='mt-5 mb-5' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createBlog()}/>
            <hr/>
            <p className='lead mb-5'><Link to='/blog' className='font-weight-bold'>Back</Link></p>
        </div>
    );
};
export default BlogDetail;
```

Comment: This issue might be caused by any number of things. You should include in your question the actual html rendered where you expect the images to show.

Comment: What is the rendered media file url ? does it open when you directly open that media url in browser ?

Comment: yes it is opening sir

Comment: my media file is connected and setup as , MEDIA_URL='/media/'                             and media root is set as MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')                  and in my main project file in urls.py there i setup correct url patterns. React seems to much complex than plain html